# PDFBox and chinese characters

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox 1.8 and I am trying to fill a pdf form with chinese character but all I got is strange characters. I got a ttc file (uming.ttc) and using font forge I exported ttf file (right now I am tryng to use only one of the exported fonts).

Loading of the fonts is done using

```
    InputStream is = ..
    PDTrueTypeFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, is);
```

and I am writing the pdf field using the following code (that I found here in stackoverflow but currently I can't found it)

```
    protected void setPDFFieldAndFont(String fieldName, String keyFontName, Object... values) {
    try {
        PDField pdField = pdfForm.getField(fieldName);
        if (pdField == null) {
            return;
        }
        // append fields to create a new textfield
        Filler filler = new Filler();
        filler.append(values);
        String textFieldString = filler.toString();
        String fontName = key2FontName.get(keyFontName);
        COSDictionary dict = pdField.getDictionary();
        COSString defaultAppearance = (COSString) dict
                .getDictionaryObject(COSName.DA);
        if (defaultAppearance != null)
        {
            dict.setString(COSName.DA, "/" + fontName + " 11 Tf");
        }
        if (pdField instanceof PDTextbox)
        {
            PDTextbox textbox = new PDTextbox(pdfForm, dict);
            //PDTextbox textbox = (PDTextbox) pdField;
            textbox.setValue(textFieldString);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid field name: " + fieldName, e);
    }
}
```

I have read that pdfbox2.0 supports unicode do I need to use this new version ?

Using font-forge I have seen that my ttf font has encoding ISO-10646-1.

Thanks for any help

**EDITED**

As asked by Tilman Hausherr I tried EmbeddedFonts.java and it works fine but I am filling the form in a different way. I created a main sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {

    String pdfform = "D:\\form.pdf";

    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfform));
    PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(doc, new File("D:\\fonts\\UMingCN.ttf"));
    PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

    PDResources res = acroForm.getDefaultResources();
    if (res == null){
        res = new PDResources();
    }
    COSName fontName = res.add(font);
    acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);



    PDField pdField = acroForm.getField("personalInformation_fullName");
    if (pdField == null) {
        return;
    }
    COSDictionary dict = pdField.getCOSObject();
    COSString defaultAppearance = (COSString) dict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.DA);
    if (defaultAppearance != null)
    {
        dict.setString(COSName.DA, "/" + fontName.getName() + " 11 Tf");
    }
    if (pdField instanceof PDTextField)
    {
        PDTextField textbox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        textbox.getCOSObject().addAll(dict);

        textbox.setValue("保保保");
    }

    doc.save("example2.pdf");
    doc.close();
}
```

but it does not fill anything. In debug the code goes to textbox.setValue but the pdfform saved does not have the value set in the pdf.
Probably I am missing something ..

Thanks again

Comment: First things first. Since you converted an original font to another type, that may be the cause of the character map being disrupted. Check that first.

Comment: Thanks, I validated generated ttf with font-forge and it seems ok.

Comment: You should try 2.0. Change the "EmbeddedFonts.java" example to test.

Comment: Please see also the CreateFormField example. You didn't add the field to the field list, i.e. acroForm.getFields().add(textbox), and you didn't add the widget to the page . (Uh, did you want to create a new field, or alter an existing field?) If first, see my remark. If second, don't create a new field.

Comment: An additional hint: use the "improved in GSoC2015 thanks to google money" PDFDebugger  ( https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-debugger/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ ) to see your PDF. (switch to "see internal structure" to see the acroform part). The best is to compare your PDF and a "good" PDF and then either you know what's to do, or you have new info to improve the question.

Comment: Thanks Tilman I solved using your suggestion.

Comment: @ErnestPoldrige best would be that you answer the question yourself, i.e. post the code that you finally used.

Comment: I didn't change my code. I received another pdf form written with a different font and I was able to print chinese characters without pdf2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issues with PdfBox and chinese (japanese, korean, and any other font) by turning text into image, like this

```
void writeLine(String text, int x, int y, int width, int height,
           Font font, Color color, PDPageContentStream contentStream, PDDocument document) throws IOException {

    try (
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ) {
        int scale = 2;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width * scale, height * scale, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_SPEED);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.scale(scale,scale);
        g2d.drawString(text, 0, g2d.getFontMetrics().getAscent());
        g2d.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        baos.close();

        contentStream.drawImage(PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(
            document,baos.toByteArray(), ""), x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Drawing a bitmap obviously always is an option when one wants to add content to a pdf, but more often than not it's a bad choice because of bad, pixelated quality and lack of support for text extraction etc.